# Why is IDENTITY preferred over GUID as primary key for data warehousing?

Tags: sql, guid, data-warehouse

I love my GUID. However, lately I have been doing some research to understand the actual pros/cons over IDENTITY for primary keys and I found [this article](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-i-choose-for-my-primary-key.html) which summarize it quite nicely.

In the article the author has put:

> - highly useful for data warehousing;

as one of the pros for using IDENTITY over GUID.

I would understand that with particularly large databases, as with data warehouses, the size does matter - however it would appear there are other reasons which the article fails to explain. So I ask:

*Why is GUID a bad idea for date warehousing?*

Comment: Also discussed on DBA.stackexchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264/guid-vs-int-which-is-better-as-a-primary-key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDENTITY fields create small, pretty indexes.  They are also SEQUENTIAL which means that indexes created for them are less fragmented than regular GUID key indexes.  Using SEQUENTIAL GUID's will get you closer to this behavior, but it still has its drawbacks.  One advantage a GUID has is that it tends to be unique even across databases, but it's a performance and space hit in most applications.

GUID Pros
Unique across every table, every database, every server
Allows easy merging of records from different databases
Allows easy distribution of databases across multiple servers
You can generate IDs anywhere, instead of having to roundtrip to the database
Most replication scenarios require GUID columns anyway

GUID Cons
It is a whopping 4 times larger than the traditional 4-byte index value; this can have serious performance and storage implications if you're not careful
Cumbersome to debug (where userid='{BAE7DF4-DDF-3RG-5TY3E3RF456AS10}')
The generated GUIDs should be partially sequential for best performance (eg, newsequentialid() on SQL 2005) and to enable use of clustered indexes

Also, to specifically answer your question :
I don't think the article you're referencing says that "GUIDs are a bad idea for data warehousing" as much as it says "Identity" fields are more useful in data warehousing than natural keys.  However, if you're storing huge amounts of records in a data warehouse, you will get better performance and smaller storage requirements from using IDENTITY columns rather than GUIDs due to the indexing complaint above, I would say that is the primary drawback.

Answer (score 19):

GUIDs may seem to be a natural choice for your primary key - and if you really must, you could probably argue to use it for the PRIMARY KEY of the table. What I'd strongly recommend **not to do** is use the GUID column as the **clustering key**, which SQL Server does by default, unless you specifically tell it not to.

You really need to keep two issues apart:

1) the **primary key** is a logical construct - one of the candidate keys that uniquely and reliably identifies every row in your table. This can be anything, really - an INT, a GUID, a string - pick what makes most sense for your scenario.

2) the **clustering key** (the column or columns that define the "clustered index" on the table) - this is a *physical* storage-related thing, and here, a small, stable, ever-increasing data type is your best pick - INT or BIGINT as your default option.

By default, the primary key on a SQL Server table is also used as the clustering key - but that doesn't need to be that way! I've personally seen massive performance gains when breaking up the previous GUID-based Primary / Clustered Key into two separate key - the primary (logical) key on the GUID, and the clustering (ordering) key on a separate `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column.

As [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) - the Queen of Indexing - and others have stated a great many times - a `GUID` as the clustering key isn't optimal, since due to its randomness, it will lead to massive page and index fragmentation and to generally bad performance.

Yes, I know - there's `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server 2005 and up - but even that is not truly and fully sequential and thus also suffers from the same problems as the `GUID` - just a bit less prominently so.

Then there's another issue to consider: the clustering key on a table will be added to **each and every entry on each and every non-clustered index** on your table as well - thus you really want to make sure it's as small as possible. Typically, an INT with 2+ billion rows should be sufficient for the vast majority of tables - and compared to a GUID as the clustering key, you can save yourself hundreds of megabytes of storage on disk and in server memory.

Quick calculation - using INT vs. GUID as Primary and Clustering Key:

- Base Table with 1'000'000 rows (3.8 MB vs. 15.26 MB)
- 6 nonclustered indexes (22.89 MB vs. 91.55 MB)

**TOTAL: 25 MB vs. 106 MB** - and that's just on a single table!

Some more food for thought - excellent stuff by Kimberly Tripp - read it, read it again, digest it! It's the SQL Server indexing gospel, really.

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEY and/or clustered key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Marc

Comment: how did you type all that so fast?

Comment: @MitchWheat: copy&paste :-) I keep getting this question over and over again - every couple of months :-)

Comment: Why not VTC this as a dupe then? Or at least address the data warehouse aspect specifically.

Comment: I'm still concerned that using a 32-bit int limits, not the number of rows in the table, but the number of inserts and deletes on a table, which could easily exceed the ~2 billion limit of a 32-bit int, since identity column don't re-use integers (it's a kind of resource leak, IMO).  Depending on the application and computer speed, even a 64-bit limit could be exceeded within the lifespan of an application, possibly even many times.  This leads me to think that we ought to just use GUIDs and be done with it, never have to worry about reseeding identities or difficulties in merging databases.

Comment: @Triynko: if you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit .... Go with `BIGINT IDENTITY` - don't even consider GUID's - and spare yourself from fragmentation hell and performance degradations.....

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason to use a 4 byte integer is because you try to keep row sizes to a minimum. Given that a fact table can contain 100 of millions of rows, a saving of 12 bytes per row is a substantial saving.

Of course, that assumes you have less than 2^31 - 1 rows...

Also, inserting into an identity column (with the default clustered index) will not result in page splits, whereas inserting with a clustered index on a GUID column will cause page splits.

Ref : [SQL Server: Is it OK to use a uniqueidentifier (GUID) as a Primary Key?](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/sql-server-is-it-ok-to-use.html)

Comment: It saves more than 4 bytes doesn't it? UniqueIdentifier is 16 bytes, so it saves 8 bytes over bigint and 12 over int.

Comment: it does, I'm tired. have fixed. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Although strictly speaking surrogate / fact ID keys should be anonymouus and meaningless, I have found that with very large facts where the reporing is based on large ranges of dates, making the surrogate key for the date an integer representing the date (e.g. 20120830) allows you to run queries without actually joining to the calendar dimension.  You wouldn't be able to do this (questionable) trick with GUIDs.  I also find it useful in dimensions to have a set of unknown members, for example in a calendar dimension, a surrogate of 0 means 'date not yet available', -1 means 'Unknown', -2 might mean 'late date' - i.e. latere than the greatest date in the calendar range. -3 might mean 'early date' etc.  This may be problematic using GUID.

Answer (score 0):

I get some thoughts after reading your question

1. GUID is primarily used in MS world.. not seen a GUID used in my 12 odd yrs of exp of DWH...
2. The Identity columns would most probably become the Surrogate key for the table, there it makes lot more sense of have them auto-increment... I am not sure if GUID can give us that kind of functionality...
3. Indexing numeric columns is whole lot faster than indexing alphanumeric columns.. numeric column based indexes are smaller in size and faster in access...

hth

Comment: GUID's are not alphanumeric, they are a hex representation of a 128 bit integer

Comment: Isnt this a GUID -> {3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301}
It might very well be a hex representation, how is it going to be generated & stored within a database ?

And, may be I have seen only one side of world, but honestly, I have not seen a single GUID kind of column used in the DWHs that I have worked with...

Answer (score -1):

Because indexing on Identity is very efficient that on GUIDs.